# Inner join failing

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have a table with an awful name, refered as D. A table named barcode refered as B.
Both tables have a column named barcode. I want to simply join the two tables on the barcode column.

See the result: 
[image]

Comment: Please post a schema and sample data, with expected and actual results. You're making it hard for us to help by posting a screen shot...

Comment: Can you do an sp_help on the table and post a screen shot? That way we will see the schema and other details

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: it's shown in the screenshot. The join brings no rows.

Comment: what are the types of the two barcode fields? If they're varchar, check if there's any whitespace/invisible chars throwing off the equality test. e.g. `123[space]` is not equal to `123`

Comment: Arthur, it must be a difference in column data type. Did you check that?

Comment: @Andrew - yeah, I'm on a crappy-resolution monitor, didn't see that first row in the screenshot

Comment: @MarcB If you want to post it as an answer, I will validate it. I just changed for "LTRIM(B.barcode) = D.barcode2 and it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are the types of the two barcode fields?

If they're varchar, check if there's any whitespace/invisible chars throwing off the equality test. e.g. `123[space]` is not equal to `123`

Comment: Bad example as `123[space]` is equal to `123` in SQL Server (and ANSI SQL AFAIK). See [How SQL Server Compares Strings with Trailing Spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/316626?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM D inner join B on CAST(rtrim(D.BarCode) as varchar) = CAST(rtrim(B.BarCode) as varchar)
```

Would probably do the trick.